# extracted jar file can not find main class

Tags: bosch-iot-suite, eclipse-vorto

Could not find or load main class org.eclipse.vorto.example.mapping.HonoPayloadApp

in the HonoPayloadApp project, I extracted the jar file, but when running the jar file, it reports cannot find the main class, the extracted actions are ensured to be correct.

java -cp hono-payloadmapping.jar org.eclipse.vorto.example.mapping.HonoPayloa
dApp start
Error: Could not find or load main class org.eclipse.vorto.example.mapping.HonoPayloadApp

Is there any restriction of the vorto codes, because as I see the jar file in winrar, it seems a little abnormal.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you firstly build the project with maven successfully with `mvn clean package` and then run it with java -jar target/xyz.jar